# ウェブサイトをどのiPadの機種（〇世代、Air/Proなど）で見ているか判定する方法は？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

私のサイトはiPadの様々な機種で閲覧することを想定しています。
タイトルのように、今どの機種のiPadでウェブサイトを閲覧しているか判定する必要に迫られています。iPad Airなのか、Proなのか、それは何世代なのか？
JavaScriptかJqueryどちらかで調べたいと考えています。

使用機種のOSはすべてiPadOS 13～15のいずれかが想定されるので、userAgentの情報を取得しても決定的な情報は取れないように思います。
何か良い方法は無いでしょうか？

※teratailにも同内容の質問を投稿しています。早く解決したい気持ちが盛ってしまいました。
https://teratail.com/questions/udz8ibufhzw4ia

Comment: 発想を転換して見ている人に選んでもらうとか？

Comment: 機種や OS 情報を取得することで何を解決したいのか、についても記載があると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。(例えば解像度等であれば UserAgent 以外の方法でも取得できるはず)

Answer (score 0):

今回はたまたまipad air 第４世代ひとつの機種を判別できれば良かったので、
画面ディスプレイのサイズを取得して判別する方法で行こうと思います。
ただ、ipad air第５世代も同じサイズ（10.9インチ）のようなので、
今回の私の場合は妥協して考えないことにしてますが、最善の方法ではないようですね…